# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\tan x}{x}\log\Big(\frac{1+b\cos x}{1+a\cos x}\Big)dx$ where -1<a<b<1

Tags: integration

Can anyone give me some hints how to evaluate this integral? Thanks.

Comment: Turn the $\log$ into a double integral like so: $$\log(1+b\cos x) - \log(1+a\cos x) = \int_a^b \frac{\cos x}{1+y\cos x} dy$$

Comment: If you dont show some work , some nice users will close your problem and as you can see a nice guy has already voted to close your question.